# Django: how to filter for rows whose fields are contained in passed value?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

`MyModel.objects.filter(field__icontains=value)` returns all the rows whose `field` contains `value`.  How to do the opposite? Namely, construct a queryset that returns all the rows whose `field` *is contained* in `value`?

Preferably without using custom SQL (ie only using the ORM) or without using backend-dependent SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`field__icontains` and similar are coded right into the ORM. The other version simple doesn't exist.

You could use the `where` param described under the [reference for QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).

In this case, you would use something like:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=["%s LIKE CONCAT('%%',field,'%%')"], params=[value])
```

Of course, do keep in mind that *there is no standard method of concatenation across DMBS*. So as far as I know, there is no way to satisfy your requirement of avoiding backend-dependent SQL.

If you're okay with working with a list of dictionaries rather than a queryset, you could always do this instead:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all().values()
matches = [r for r in qs if value in r[field]]
```

although this is of course not ideal for huge data sets.